# Python /Plotly/Geopandas

Tags: python, plotly, geopandas

I keep on getting this error , and have read others online getting in ,

````
ImportError: geopandas, pyshp and shapely must be installed for this figure factory.

Run the following commands to install the correct versions of the following modules:

```
pip install geopandas==0.3.0
pip install pyshp==1.2.10
pip install shapely==1.6.3
```
If you are using Windows, follow this post to properly install geopandas and dependencies:http://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/

If you are using Anaconda, do not use PIP to install the packages above. Instead use conda to install them:

```
conda install plotly

conda install geopanda
````

The thing is , I have installed plotly/geopanda via the methods above and it still does not work , but when I import plotly, geopand alone it does not throw an error. really when I break down my code  below, this line is what is throwing the error: `ff.create_choropleth` - my full code is below:

```
import plotly, geopandas
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df_sample = pd.read_excel('popdata.xlsx') # Read in your data
values = df_sample['Change'].tolist() # Read in the values contained within your file
fips = df_sample['FIPS'].tolist() # Read in FIPS Codes

colorscale = ["#171c42","#223f78","#1267b2","#4590c4","#8cb5c9","#b6bed5","#dab2be",
              "#d79d8b","#c46852","#a63329","#701b20","#3c0911"]

endpts = list(np.linspace(-75, 75, len(colorscale) - 1)) # Identify a suitable range for your data

#fig = ff.create_choropleth(
  # fips=fips, values=values, colorscale=colorscale, show_state_data=True, binning_endpoints=endpts, # If your values is a list of numbers, you can bin your values into half-open intervals
   # county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5}, 
   # legend_title='% change', title='% Change in disease between 1980-2014'
#)
py.plot(fig, filename='diseasechange')
```

Comment: And what error do you get? (can you show the full traceback?)

Comment: The import error. At the very top of my post

Comment: Ah, when I get back from work I’ll post the trace back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install geopandas==0.8.1
```

fixed this issue for me.

Comment: It saved the day, thank you a lot! I tried all that was written in the traceback message but they didn't help, this did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `import plotly figure_factory as ff` and then `ff.create_choropleth` try this:

```
# import necessary libraries
import geopandas
import shapely
import shapefile
import plotly
from plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth import create_choropleth
import xlrd
# Check your version
print(plotly.__version__, geopandas.__version__,shapely.__version__,shapefile.__version__)
# Data
df_sample = pd.read_excel('popdata.xlsx') # Read in your data
values = df_sample['Change'].tolist() # Read in the values contained within your file
fips = df_sample['FIPS'].tolist() # Read in FIPS Codes

colorscale = ["#171c42","#223f78","#1267b2","#4590c4","#8cb5c9","#b6bed5","#dab2be",
              "#d79d8b","#c46852","#a63329","#701b20","#3c0911"]

endpts = list(np.linspace(-75, 75, len(colorscale) - 1)) # Identify a suitable range for your data

fig = create_choropleth(
   fips=fips, values=values, colorscale=colorscale, show_state_data=True, binning_endpoints=endpts, # If your values is a list of numbers, you can bin your values into half-open intervals
    county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5}, 
    legend_title='% change', title='% Change in disease between 1980-2014'
)
# Plot in offline mode and save plot in your Python script folder
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='diseasechange.html')
```

Also, if you have problem with `import shapely` or `import shapefile` you will need install it